# Eclipse C++ project with subfolders

Tags: c++, eclipse, project

I am solving a lot of LeetCode problems with C++.
I work in Eclipse and want to create a file structure like:

```
Leetcode 
        Topic1
              Problem1
                     solution.cpp
              Problem2
                     solution.cpp
              Problem3
                     solution.cpp
        Topic2
              Problem1
                     solution.cpp
              Problem2
                     solution.cpp
              Problem3
                     solution.cpp
```

I want every solution.cpp file to be run independently from all other solution files...

But whenever I create a subfolder inside project and place a cpp file there the project stops to Build and can't run. For example this doesn't build or run :

> Leetcode/Binary_Search/349.Intersection-of-two-arrays/349.Intersection-of-Two-Arrays.cpp
>   Leetcode/Binary_Search/4.Median-of-two-sorted-arrays/4.median-of-two-sorted-arrays.cpp
>   Leetcode/Array/1.Two-Sum/1.Two-Sum.cpp

(here *Leetcode* is Workspace, _Binary_Search_ and *Array* are projects, *4.Media-of-two-sorted-arrays* and *1.Two-Sum* are Folders and respective **.cpp* files are solutions)

I understand that I am lacking the knowledge of how Eclipse project folders for C++ are organized. Can anyone help me? If you send me a link for what to read I'll appreciate it.

Comment: I wonder why your build fails as soon as you just place new cpp files there. Could it be that you have chosen "C++ Managed Build" as project type? In this case eclipse will try to compile all cpp files and link them. This is probably not what you want if you want your cpp files be run independently from the other ones. Anyway, there is not enough information in your post to really understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that explains how the file structure of eclipse works

https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse143/11wi/eclipse-tutorial/file_organization.shtml

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.